# Parser and Lexer rules overlap

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I have grammar in Antlr4, to parse and validate a custom made language. Among others my grammar should consider as 'valid' the following

> // Assign string value to a variable
>   `myVar = 'aString';`
>   // Function with string argument
>   `firstFunction('thisIsAnArg');`
>   // Function with string argument, which have specific format (date)
>   `secondFunction('26/06/2016');`

Below are the 'relevant' parts of my grammar

```
/*
 * Parser Rules
*/
function_call
     : firstFunction'(' literal ')'
     | secondFunction '(' date_formated_string ')'

literal
    : SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING
    | date_formated_string
    | '(' literal ')'  // recursive parentheses
    ;

date_formated_string
    : '\'' day = (TWO_DIGITS | ONE_DIGIT) ('/') month = (TWO_DIGITS | ONE_DIGIT) ('/') year = FOUR_DIGITS '\'';

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */
SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING:            '\'' (~'\'' | '\'\'')* '\'';
```

The problem here is that the argument of the `secondFunction` is parsed by the lexer as `SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING`, thus the parser throws an exception, when tries to match `secondFunction`. A solution would be to move the `date_formated_string` rule to the lexer. However this way I will lose the ability to have the date separated in (day, month, year) in my `Listener` class.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Well that date **is** a string, so what you should do is parse it as a string, then do a custom validation pass over the output. Don't try to put *everything* into the grammar.

Comment: That can be a solution. However I defined and I am try to follow, the following design. (1) All structure validations should be on grammar (2) Listener will contain 'logic' validations (3) I can have multiple different listeners based on the different context my grammar will be used. I am not saying that my logic is correct and yours is wrong, or vise-versa but in order to follow your solution I need to revise it. @LucasTrzesniewski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Although I was 'negative' at the beginning for various reasons (see question's comments discussion), I decided to follow @LucasTrzesniewski and put the additional validation logic into the code and not the grammar file.

The logic is simple:

- I created a `ValidationListener` which extends / inherits the `BaseListener` that was created when building the grammar (.g4 file). I overrode any method where I needed to do any additional validations. In my case I overrode the `EnterFunction_call`
- Every `Listener` I make from now for now has to extend / inherit `ValidationListener` instead of `BaseListener`.
- Every time I am overriding a method in any `Listener` the overrides the `ValidationListener`, I have to ensure the `base.{methodName}()` is called first in order for 'custom' validations to run before anything else.

I could have put the validations directly on every `Listener` I create and omit the `ValidationListener`, but most of the validations are common among the listeners (as I said on question I was hoping to put them on the grammar level) and using the aforementioned design I can achieve better separation. However there is a small (IMHO) drawback regarding code maintenance, since as I said, I have to ensure that the `base.{methodName}()` is called first, which is a 'manual' step that someone may forget to do.